# Set WaitTimeOut for Azure Service Bus Session Processor

Tags: c#, azure-servicebus-queues

In the legacy version of Azure Service Bus (ASB) I can use MessageWaitTimeout in SessionHandlerOptions to control the timeout between 2 messages. For example, if I set timeout 5 seconds, after complete the first message, the queue waits for 5s then picks the next message.

In the new version Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus, the queue has to wait for around 1 minute to pick up the next message. I only need to process one-by-one messages, no need to process concurrent messages.

I follow this [example](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/servicebus/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/samples/Sample05_SessionProcessor.md) and can't find any solution to set timeout like the old version.
Does anyone know how to do it?

```
var options = new ServiceBusSessionProcessorOptions
{
    AutoCompleteMessages = false,
    MaxConcurrentSessions = 1,
    MaxConcurrentCallsPerSession = 1,
    MaxAutoLockRenewalDuration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2),
};
```

EDIT:
I found the solution. It is RetryOptions in ServiceBusClient

```
var client = new ServiceBusClient("connectionString", new ServiceBusClientOptions
{
    RetryOptions = new ServiceBusRetryOptions
    {
        TryTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the latest stable release, 7.2.0, this can be configured with the [SessionIdleTimeout property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebussessionprocessoroptions.sessionidletimeout?view=azure-dotnet-preview).